# подставить строки на Python c условием

Tags: python

Есть документ с некоторым небольшим колисеством строк( не более 45 ).
Нужно подставить в него 2 строки string1 и string2 любым способом со следующими условиями:
Строка string1 должна идти после строки содержащей фразу `priorityid`
Строка string2 должна идти после строки содержащей фразу 'resourceid'
Обе фразы всегда встречаются в тексте только 1 раз.

Comment: Вы что то пробовали самостоятельно?

Comment: Если нужно подставить строки — подставляйте. Мы не возражаем.

Comment: способ на баше, который описал GareevAydar - вполне подходит. Хотелось бы понять - как можно реализовать подобный функциона л в Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эту проблему можно решить с помощью sed (Если у вас используется linux-like ОС)
Примерная команда выглядит так:

```
> cat text
...
priorityid
...
resourceid
...

cat 123.txt|sed -e "s/\(priorityid\)/\1\nstring1/g" -e "s/\(resourceid\)/\1\nstring2/g"
```